# Eclipse Web Tool Platform Vs Tomcat sysdeo Plugin in developing web application

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have started learning to create web application using Eclispse a few months ago.
I saw that some of the web project are created using new>tomcat project while others are created by new>dynamic web project.
How are they different.
One more thing I would like to know is to apply dynamic web project we must run tomcat server using WTP and tomcat project using tomcat plugin.
Is this right or wrong?